# Finding comma seprated values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, automation, calendar

[image]

I want t to compare the value of the 6th raw with the dates comma separated in `O` column and accordingly if the date is present in that column then correspondingly it should enter `L` otherwise 1 (Present), basically, column o is a leave date and want to fill the calendar accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(U6,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($O$9,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),0)),"L",1)
```

You can also try-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT(U6,"d/m/e"),O9)),"L",1)
```

[image]

Comment: If it works then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it).

Comment: thankyou so much, can you help me with one more thing, 
I have two excel sheets and have to use data of one sheet two another and using if function for that so it contains file path but I have to change every time with every cell when a new file is introduced, I use it is there a way that I can enter file path once and in any cell and then it will grab it from there?

Comment: @MeetLathiya Better ask a separate question with sample data.